# Русское БИТЬ, БАТОЖИТЬ

Tags: фонетика

Разъясните, возможна ли следующая этимология:

От русск. **БИТЬ**, пульсировать — лат. PAL**PITO** – пульсировать, биться, трепетать, дрожать, PAL**PITA**TIO – пульсирование, биение (переход Б-П) 
англ. **PUL**S(AT)E, **BEAT** – пульсировать.

От **БИЛ**СЯ ‒ лат. **PUL**SO – сильно стучать, ударять, **PUL**SUS – толчок, удар, пульс, биение пульса, **PUL**SATIO – биение, стук (переход Б-П), англ. **PUL**SE – пульс, фран. **POUL**S – пульс.

От **БИТ**ЬСЯ ‒ лат. **BAT**TUO – бить, избивать, **BAT**UO, **BAT**UI – бить, биться, колотить, **PEL**LO – бить, толкать, поражать, **BEL**LUM – война, **BEL**LO – воевать, сражаться, **BEL**LONA – богиня войны, **BEL**LATOR – ратник, **BEL**LICUS, **BEL**LICOSUS, **BEL**LAX – воинский, воинственный.

Так же арх.лат. **DUEL**LUM – война ‒ то же самое, что и **BEL**LUM, поскольку латинские b и d отличаются лишь ориентацией.

В нем. **BEIL** – топор, **BEUT**E – добыча. 
В англ. **ВАТ** – бита, **BAT**TLE – битва, **BEAT** – бить, **BUT**TER – масло (взбитое), **BEAT**EN – побежденный, **BAT**TUE – бойня, резня, A**BAT**TOIR – бойня, скотобойня.

В исп. **BEL**ICO – военный, A**BAT**IDO – удрученный, подавленный (от УБИТЫЙ горем), A**BAT**IR – валить, сваливать, унижать, рубить.

Во франц. **BUT** – мишень.

В греч. **BIA** (БИА) – сила, насилие, принуждение, μπήγω (**БИГО**) – вбивать (перепутали Т и Г).

От русск. **БИТЬ** поклоны, молиться ‒ нем. **BET**EN – молиться.

**БЕСТИЯ**, **БЕС**, **БИЧ** ‒ в одном смысловом кусте со словом **БИТЬ** ‒ в лат. **PESTIS** – бич, чума, зараза, повальная болезнь, гибель, разрушение, моровая язва.

В англ. **PEST** – бич, паразит, язва, мор, чума.

**БАТОЖИТЬ**, **БИТЬ** **БАТОГАМИ**. **БАТОГ** (владимирское, костромское…) выражение, означающее палка, хворостина (В.Даль) ‒ находим: 
В английском **ВАТ** – (спорт.) бита, бить битой.
Во фран. **BATON** – палка.
В исп. **BATIR** – бить, побить.
В итал. **BAST**ONE – палка.
А в португальском **BAT**EDOURO – кувалда.

Во всех приведенных примерах ярко проявляется русский корневой костяк **БТ** (**bt**). Складывается впечатление, что именно русский корень стал основой для указанных иностранных слов. Но разве возможно такое, если история уверяет, что указанные культуры – английская, немецкая, греческая, латинская… ‒ существовали задолго до появления славян?

Comment: А что такое 'корневой костяк'? И вообще какие -то вопросы у вас одинаковые. Берете 
разные слова и хотите, чтобы с вами согласились в том, что именно от русских слов все 
другие образовались. Причем никому все равно не верите, ни с кем не соглашаетесь.

Comment: Никому не верю?

Comment: "Корневой костяк" - костяк корневых согласных.
При заимствованиях слов западноевропейцами не всегда брались в расчет гласные звуки (буквы). Кроме того, гласные могли трансформироваться при узаконении грамматики (17-19 вв.). Не говорю уже о способе произношения (озвучивания) одних и тех же латинских букв в различных западноевропейских языках. Поэтому - надежда, в основном, на согласные, на их  костяк.

Comment: Далее. Мы должны с вами "восприять" один "странный" факт - наличие схожих русско-иностранных пар сразу по 2-3 параметрам  (имеются ввиду - неславянские ,т.н. западноевропейские языки). Это, как правило, семантика и графика, реже - фонетика. 

Таких пар больше, чем принято считать. Многие из них даже не упоминаются в академических словарях.
Их не единицы, как уверяет Зализняк, и не десятки, а гораздо больше.
Это уже - статистика.

Поэтому, не учитывать этот фактический материал при лингв. анализе - недопустимо. Недобросовестно. Как бы ни труден был этот вопрос, его как-то надо решать.

Comment: Не сразу, но решать.

Answer (score 1):

Глагол "бить" имеет и.-е. корень bh(ei)/bhoi и о.-с. основу biti, где  t  - это общеславянский расширитель.

В других индоевропейских языках встречаются другие расширители (l, r), например: Beil (нем.) - топор, bir (арм.) - дубина.

Comment: Чтобы нас понимало большинство интересующихся русским языком, не только профессионалы, можно попробовать писать более простым и последовательным языком.

Например, что значит - "Глагол "бить" имеет и.-е. корень bh(ei)/bhoi и о.-с. основу biti, где t - это общеславянский расширитель", если перевести это на бытовой язык?

Comment: Это цитата из этимологического словаря П.Я. Черных, я ее понимаю так. В языках индоевропейской группы общим является корневой формант "б+ гласный", причем гласные могут меняться (сравнить: бить - бей - бой), а согласный составляет устойчивую часть корня. В славянских языках к и.-е. корню добавляется согласный t (расширитель, суффиксальный формант), в других и.-е. языках могут присутствовать другие расширители. Из этого можно сделать вывод, все приведенные вами слова имеют общее и.-е. происхождение.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ, Вера!
У меня вопрос по корням. 
Справедливо ли считать русск. БОЙ и БИЧ однокоренными с БЕЙ, БИТЬ?
Думаю, да.

Comment: Тогда что у Черных может означать мысль - "В славянских языках к и.-е. корню добавляется согласный t" ?
Ведь в русском языке, как мы видим, предостаточно слов с указанным индоевропейским корнем b- (т.е. b+гласный) без этой самой расширительной t.

Comment: Что же тогда имел ввиду Павел Черных?

Comment: Вообще-то у Черных идет речь о реконструкции слов. Например, мы наблюдаем за современными славянскими языками и определяем их общую основу, которую называем праславянской. Затем сравниваем с другими и.-е. языками, убираем расширители и восстанавливаем общий и.-е. корень. А какие слова в русском языке состоят из двух звуков: б+ гласный переднего ряда (И,Е)?. Существует глагол быть (это твердый вариант, гласный непереднего ряда), он также имеет о.-с. основу byti и и.-е. корень bhu. У слова "бич" о.-с. основа bic, др.-рус. бичь с 13 века, чередование К/Ч.

Answer (score 0):

Я подхожу к проблеме с другой стороны.
Для Вас (как и для многих) славянские языки заранее и хорошо известны.
Перечислять не будем.

Для меня - западноевропейские - тот же самый славянский ореол.
Не удивляйтесь этому.

У меня собрано предостаточно исторических свидетельств такому утверждению.
Период 16-19 вв. - период заимствования и одновременно ухода Западной Европы от славянства. И не только лишь в языке.

Религия, история, география, династии... - всё так или иначе было подменено, переписано, подделано и т.д.

Понимаю, это для нас не легко принять, учитывая все те "античные и средневековые" свершения, которые Европа с легкой руки историков, богословов и политиков якобы достигла и закрепила. Но, поверьте, на деле тема "старой Европы" не стоит и выеденного яйца.

За триста с небольшим последних лет свободного плавания Зап. Европа, однако, смогла вырваться вперед, и по отношению к своему славянскому прошлому - значительно от него оторвалась, "отчуждилась", "отпротестантиздилась", если можно так говорить. И это был её выбор.

(Огромное, довлеющее влияние славянства на всей территории Европы в период 13-16 веков несомненно. Перечислять все свидетельства здесь нет возможности).
Учитывая сказанное, уместнее считать западную языковую культуру - смесью славянства и доморощенного западничества.

Исходя из этого, мне приходится сравнивать не только так называемые славянские корни, но и остальные "неславянские".
И, как Вы понимаете, результаты получаются иные. По-другому и не может быть.

Тем более, что поводов для такого подхода западно-европейские языки дают предостаточно.

Это не значит, что мне чужда научная этимология.
Нет, она мне интересна и полезна.
И я благодарен Вам за развернутый ответ.
Частично он должен отразиться в моих исследованиях по заимствованиям.

Знать надо все стороны.

Comment: >> Религия, история, география, династии... - всё так или иначе было подменено, переписано, подделано и т.д.

Ну конечно! Без этого все ваши (и подобных вам "мыслителей") построения не катят совершенно. А так — отчего ж... Вам — факты, а вы — "подделка". Неплохо устроились. С Фоменко взяли пример? ))))

Comment: Что ж, может поговорим о некоторых примерах?

Comment: О каких примерах?! Вы утверждаете, что латынь произошла от славянских языков – всё, какие могут быть разговоры. Вы даже не понимаете, что этим зачеркивается ВСЯ лингвистика, не говоря уж об истории. Если это вас не волнует, могу сказать одно: вы плоховато учились в школе.

Comment: Оценивать мою личность сейчас не стоит.
Поговорим о деле.
Лингвистике 100 с небольшим лет.
Первым, прото-лингвистам, - триста.
Об этих мы мало знаем. Но они, судя по переделкам в языках 17-18 веков, не могли не быть. Примитивные, но были. Так или иначе надо было обосновывать нормы новых национальных языков.

Comment: Напомню Вам, что Зап.Европа до 16 века не имела (а на деле - и позже) единых национальных языков. Само по себе - это странно. Старая, античная, могучая Европа не могла определиться не то что с единой общенациональной  границей (как когда-то Русь), но даже с местечковыми национальными языками. Английский, немецкий, французский, итальянский и т.д. - всё это молодые языки. 

Отсыл к якобы их древним предкам, например, к древнегерманскому - этакая шутка новой политической эпохи. Но это отдельный разговор. Ведь настоящих древних письменных источников не найдено до сих пор.

Comment: Сплошные копии, и копии копий.

Мы к этому привыкли и поэтому верим в любые сказки о древности Европы и влиянии ее языков на русский.

Лучше всего без философий просто рассмотреть несколько примеров русско-европейских пар на предмет возможного заимствования и попытаться ответить, например, на такой вопрос: Каким образом могли появиться те или иные схожие по письму, звучанию и смыслу слова?

Дать Вам несколько таких примеров?
Посмотрите на них глазами лингвиста?
А мы посмотрим на Ваши комментарии.
Хорошо?

Comment: >> Английский, немецкий, французский, итальянский и т.д. - всё это молодые языки.

Да, им всего-то лет по сто.

Вы уже приводили несколько "пар", спасибо. Я же говорю: прочтите книжки, написанные, так сказать, "для любознательных школьников". Таких книг много, и они вполне доступны, с интернетом-то.

Comment: Niemand, думаю, не стоит ввязываться в этот спор. После этого десанта мультов искать смысл в троллинге - дело модератора.     

Тут помимо перечисленных я еще парочку старых знакомых обнаружил. Админу я написал, удивительно, но они эти письма читают.
Можете поддержать для гарантии (expert@sezn.ru) - я все-таки свои подозрения не могу утвердить как истину, а двое - уже что-то.  
А тут что-то доказывать бессмысленно.